# How to make http response in multiple times

Tags: php, api, http, server

I have a PHP-based REST API, is that possible to get multiple HTTP responses after I sent the request only once? or is there a way to achieve this goal?

for example, I send an HTTP request for updating a bunch of data, and I need the API response with the status after each process so I can show the % on the page, very similar to the loading bar.

currently, my php response header as below

```
http_response_code(200);
echo json_encode(
  array(
    "result" => "Request finished.", 
    "success" => true,
    "progress" => $progress,
    )
);
```

it only shows 100% once all actions are done, and I learned the once code 200 been sent to the client, the HTTP connection has been closed. I also tried return code 100, but not failed.

Comment: HTTP doesn't work like that, sorry. PHP can buffer the output and send it back gradually when responding to a browser request, but it just appends more content to the page to show the results, it wouldn't allow you to update a progress bar or anything.

Comment: How many items are you updating? how long is your request taking, that you feel you need a progress bar? I suggest maybe either you split your requests up into individual update requests (but that might be inefficient for large quantities), or perhaps use websockets for the communication instead.

Comment: PHP has a mechanism to track file upload progress via the session - although that is a “pull” in terms of getting the current progress, you have to run a periodic AJAX request or something. But you could probably implement something similar. Your API would have to start the session, update the current progress, and then immediately close the session again (otherwise the session data file will be locked, so no other scripts will be able to access it at the same time) - and that multiple times.

Comment: thanks for your advice ADyson, as this is a small project, and I might split the request into four or five segments, and this should be fine.